# Auto calculation in table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**My Requirment:**

I have table with quantity cell as editable when change quantity it need to multiply with other parent td value.and sum the column values .
(i.e) if i change quantity to 2 then the parent rows need multiply by 2 & columns get value get added

I done all the calculation part the only thing when i delete or change the quantity the calculated value remain same how to revert back to old values

**Here is my fiddle**
[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hahkarthick/42gv9qu6/7/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.quantity').on('change, keyup',function(){
       var val=$(this).text();
     // To avoid auto inc while pressing arrow keys
         var preVal =$(this).data('prevval');
        <!--  console.log(preVal); -->
      if(preVal && preVal == val){
          return;
      }
      $(this).data('prevval',val);
     //To avoid auto inc while pressing arrow keys //
 if(val =='' ||  isNaN(val) || val < 1){
 return;
 }
      $(this).siblings().each(function(){
          var tbvalue=$(this).text();
          var result= parseInt(tbvalue)*parseInt(val);
          
          $(this).text(result);
      }) 
autoSum();
  });

autoSum();
});
function autoSum(){
      for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.auto_sum>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(' + i + ')').each(function() {
          sum += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;
        });
        // set total in last cell of the column
        $('.auto_sum>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(' + i + ')').last().html(sum);
       // $('.auto_sum>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(' + i + ')').last().toggleClass('total');
      }
}
```

```css
.total {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Table calculation</h2>
  <p>Calculaton</p>            
  <table class="auto_sum table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>value1</th>
        <th>value2</th>
        <th>value3</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number" contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td type>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number" contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number"  contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
        <tr class="total">
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside every row, with the td that store the numbers to be multiplied, keep the original numbers in a data-val attribute in the td, and multiply your content editable value with that. Display the multiplied value as the td text. One change here is that, when you delete the value of contenteditable cell, it takes it as 1 for row calculation, but does not consider it for column multiplication.

```
HTML part
<div class="container">
  <h2>Table calculation</h2>
  <p>Calculaton</p>            
  <table class="auto_sum table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>value1</th>
        <th>value2</th>
        <th>value3</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-val="10">10</td>
        <td data-val="5">5</td>
        <td data-val="4">4</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number" contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-val="8">8</td>
        <td data-val="2">2</td>
        <td data-val="3">3</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number" contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-val="20">20</td>
        <td data-val="3">3</td>
        <td data-val="5">5</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number"  contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
        <tr class="total">
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS Part

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.quantity').on('change, keyup',function(){
       var val=$(this).text();
     // To avoid auto inc while pressing arrow keys
         var preVal =$(this).data('prevval');

      $(this).data('prevval',val);
     //To avoid auto inc while pressing arrow keys //
 if(val =='' ||  isNaN(val) || val < 1 || val == undefined){
    val = 1;
 }

      $(this).siblings().each(function(){  
          var tbvalue=$(this).data("val");
           var result= parseInt(tbvalue)*parseInt(val);
          $(this).text(result);
      });
autoSum();
  });

autoSum();
});
function autoSum(){
      for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        var sum = 0;
        var tdBoxes = $('.auto_sum>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(' + i + ')');
        for(var j=0; j<tdBoxes.length-1;j++)
        {
          var value = $(tdBoxes[j]).text();
          //alert(value);
          sum += (value == undefined || value == "")? 0 : parseInt(value);
        }
        // set total in last cell of the column
        $('.auto_sum>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(' + i + ')').last().html(sum);
       // $('.auto_sum>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(' + i + ')').last().toggleClass('total');
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All details are commented in working demo. I added `<form>`, `<output>`, `<input type='number'>` and `<input type='hidden'>`. Also I don't remember `<td>` having a `type` attribute or a value of `number` either.

With the combination of the right elements and attributes (and maybe even a little CSS), you don't have to write so much JS/jQ because there many aspects of form functions built within HTML.

## Demo

```js
// Reference the <form>
var main = document.forms.main;

// Reference of all of <input> and <output> of <form>
var field = main.elements;

/* Register the input event on the <form>
|| ANY input event triggered within <form> will...
*/
main.addEventListener('input', function(e) {

  // Check to see which field is the user inputing into
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
  
    // Reference that field
    var input = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
    // console.log(input.value);
    
    // Get the row of the field
    var row = input.parentNode.parentNode;
    // console.log(row);
    
    /* Gather all hidden fields of that row into a NodeList
    || and convert that NodeList into an array.
    */
    var rowArray = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('[type=hidden]'));
    // console.log(rowArray);
    
    // On each hidden field, perform the following function...
    rowArray.forEach(function(cel, idx) {
    
      // Get the value of hidden field
      const base = cel.value;
      
      // Find the <output> that comes after the hidden field
      var output = cel.nextElementSibling;
      
      /* Calculate the product of the hidden field's value
      || and the input field's value
      */
      var val = parseInt(base, 10) * parseInt(input.value, 10);
      
      // Display the prouct in the <output>
      output.value = val;
    });
    
    /* Because we registered the input event on the <form>,
    || we have many ways to manipulate the <form>'s fields.
    || In this demo we have been using: 
    || HTMLFormElement and HTMLFormControlsCollection interfaces 
    || https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement
    || http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/references.php#dom0
    */
    field.out1.value = Number(field.o1a.value) + Number(field.o1b.value) + Number(field.o1c.value);

    field.out2.value = Number(field.o2a.value) + Number(field.o2b.value) + Number(field.o2c.value);

    field.out3.value = Number(field.o3a.value) + Number(field.o3b.value) + Number(field.o3c.value);

    field.out4.value = Number(field.out1.value) + Number(field.out2.value) + Number(field.out3.value);

  }
});
```

```css
.total {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input,
output {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  width: 6ch;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.quantity input {
  padding-top: .5em;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
-
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form id='main'>
      <table class="auto_sum table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <caption>
            <h2>Table Calculation</h2>
            <h3>Quanities</h3>
          </caption>
          <tr>
            <th>Value1</th>
            <th>Value2</th>
            <th>Value3</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id='rowA'>
            <td>
              <!--[0][1]-->
              <input id='v1a' type='hidden' value='10'>
              <output id='o1a'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td>
              <!--[2][3]-->
              <input id='v2a' type='hidden' value='5'>
              <output id='o2a'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td>
              <!--[4][5]-->
              <input id='v3a' type='hidden' value='4'>
              <output id='o3a'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td class="quantity">
              <!--[6]-->
              <input id='qa' type='number' value='0' max='999' min='0'>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id='rowB'>
            <td>
              <!--[7][8]-->
              <input id='v1b' type='hidden' value='8'>
              <output id='o1b'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td>
              <!--[9][10]-->
              <input id='v2b' type='hidden' value='2'>
              <output id='o2b'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td>
              <!--[11][12]-->
              <input id='v3b' type='hidden' value='3'>
              <output id='o3b'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td class="quantity">
              <!--[13]-->
              <input id='qb' type='number' value='0' max='999' min='0'>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id='rowC'>
            <td>
              <!--[14][15]-->
              <input id='v1c' type='hidden' value='20'>
              <output id='o1c'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td>
              <!--[16][17]-->
              <input id='v2c' type='hidden' value='3'>
              <output id='o2c'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td>
              <!--[18][19]-->
              <input id='v3c' type='hidden' value='5'>
              <output id='o3c'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td class="quantity">
              <!--[20]-->
              <input id='qc' type='number' value='0' max='999' min='0'>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="total">
            <td>
              <!--[21]-->
              <output id='out1' for='o1a o1b o1c'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td>
              <!--[22]-->
              <output id='out2' for='o2a o2b o2c'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td>
              <!--[23]-->
              <output id='out3' for='o3a o3b o3c'>0</output>
            </td>
            <td>
              <!--[24]-->
              <output id='out4' for='out1 out2 out3'>0</output>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```